# ¿Cómo separar el idioma del texto (similar QTranslate) en PHP?

Tags: php

En javasript utilizo la siguiente función:

```
function getText(text, lang) {
  var re = new RegExp("<!--:" + lang + "-->(.*?)<!--:-->");
  return text.match(re)[1];
}

getText("<!--:es-->Fotos<!--:--><!--:en-->Pictures<!--:-->", "es");
// retorna "Fotos"
```

Me gustaría convertir el código en PHP y añdir alguna funcionalidad de más, en caso que la cadena no sea multiidioma no haga nada y en caso que si un idioma no se encuentra dentro de la cadena devuelve el primero definido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aporto mi propia solución:

- Si la cadena no es de estilo multi-idioma devuelve la misma.
- En caso de no existir el idioma dentro de la cadena, devuelve el primero, que
  seria el idioma por defecto.

Función getTextQT

```
function getTextQT($text, $lang) {
    if ($text == null) {
        return $text;
    } else {
        $regexp = '/<\!--:(\w+?)-->([^<]+?)<\!--:-->/i';
        if(preg_match_all($regexp, $text, $matches)) {
            $res= array();
            $count = count($matches[0]);
            for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
                $res[$matches[1][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];
            }
            //print_r($res);

            return array_key_exists($lang,$res) ? $res[$lang] : $res[key($res)];
        } else return $text;
    }
}
```

#### Banco de pruebas

```
$str = "<!--:es-->Fotos<!--:--><!--:en-->Pictures<!--:--><!--:ru-->
фотографии<!--:-->";

echo "Sin multi-idioma:" .getTextQT("soy un texto de un solo idioma", "en");
echo "<br />";
echo "cadena en raw" . htmlentities($str);
echo "Mostrar [es]" . getTextQT($str, "es");
echo "<br />";
echo "Mostrar [ru]" . getTextQT($str, "ru");
echo "<br />";
echo "Mostrar [de]" . getTextQT($str, "de");
```

**Resultado**

```
Sin multi-idioma:soy un texto de un solo idioma
cadena raw<!--:es-->Fotos<!--:--><!--:en-->Pictures<!--:--><!--:ru--> фотографии<!--:-->Mostrar [es]Fotos
Mostrar [ru] фотографии
Mostrar [de]Fotos
```